# Five-Minute Comics: Part 2

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

<sub>*Part of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)*</sub>

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Didn't actually follow the five minute rule this time -- though i guess i should have, because i nearly ran out of time! There's only 10 minutes left in the day for me. Also these aren't comics, and while we're at it, this is actually the 13th part in my series of puzzles.

Visited some ideas that I never ended up getting to make with smaller minipuzzles.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Genetic Analysis

> Each of these can have a three-letter RNA codon (sequence of A, G, C, and U) to make a word:
>
>  **AUG**MENTATION
>  G**UAC**AMOLE
>  COLLE**AGU**ES
>  MORT**GAG**ORS
>  EVA**CUA**TING
>  ???
>
>  When these are converted to DNA (change U to T), their [abbreviations](http://www.hgmd.cf.ac.uk/docs/cd_amino.html) spell **MYSELF**.

## Qwertial Aphasia

> The clue answers are FED, MUK, I'M JK, LOKI, I, HUN
>
>  The used keys on a QWERTY keyboard for each answer are all near each other. Interpreting them as Braille spells **HOT GAS**.

## A New Captcha Approach

> [image]
>  The text spells **COURSE**, taking the large border to be a C.

## Choices, part 5 *(solved by Phenomist)*

> Each word can have its fifth letter changed to spell another word; the new letters spell **IRONIC**.

## Time Management

> ...The answer is **EARWAX**.

## Meta

> The answers are:
>
> ```
> MYSELF
> ??????
> HOTGAS
> COURSE
> IRONIC
> EARWAX
> ```
>
> The diagonals spell MATRIX and FIGURE.

Comment: The last one in the first puzzle also happens to be what I said upon finding out I needed a common word with UUC in it.
Just in case, yes, the final answer is that (6 6) not-really-a-phrase-but-whatever you got

Comment: Couldn't it be simply rot13(Shhhhhhhpx)?

Answer (score 5):

## Partial answer

Qwertial Aphasia (partial)

> Solving the clues - Was given food (3) = FED, Gooey Pokemon (3) = MUK, "Only Joking" (1'1 2) = I'M JK?, Thor's bro (4) = LOKI, Stacksfiller (1) = I, Mulan's enemy (3) = HUN, one thing I notice is that each is very clustered on a QWERTY keyboard. I thought that it could have to do with shifting positions on the keyboard (e.g. HUN can be shifted to the left 4 spaces to make SEX) but other than the trivial I to A, I couldn't find any other words.

Choices: Part 5

> Each word can have its fifth letter (from "Part 5") replaced with a different letter to make another word - INFLICTING, DELIRIOUS, PROMOTER, THINNING, CONFIRMATION, SMOOCHED. The new letters spell out **IRONIC**.